# Import cycles more than two levels go

Tags: go, data-structures, circular-dependency

So i have this import cycle to solve, and my project structure basically likes this:

> model.go -> procedure.go -> function.go

In my function i need model and i use interface to handle it. Currently my code basically like this:

```
type imodel interface {
    foo()
}

type model struct {
}

func (m *model) run() {
    proc := &procedure{}
    proc.run(m)
}

func (m *model) foo() {
    //bla bla
}

type procedure struct {
}

func (p *procedure) run(model imodel) {
    funct := &function{}
    funct.run(model)
}

type function struct {
}

func (f *function) run(model imodel) {
    model.foo()
}
```

My question is should i pass my model using interface thorough every class like that or there's any other workaround?

Comment: Such tightly coupled structs are best placed into the same package.

Comment: Put everything in one package. Extract packages from there if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put all of these in the same package. Depending on circumstances, I may put them in different files in the same package.

Also, you do not seem to export `imodel`, so it would be package-internal and unless you have multiple concrete implementations, you do not need an interface. Then, "imodel" is a less than ideal name, the interface should be named `model` and each concrete type implementing the interface should be named after what it models.

Comment: Would it be still ideal, if i have many classes and the package getting bulky?

Comment: If you are using an interface, the interface is the *interesting* bit, and should thus not have an unsightly reminder that it is an interface in its name. And unless you 100% need the abstraction of an interface (usually because you have multiple things that need slightly different implementation of the relevant interface methods), it should be avoided.